Making an program for sending token infos to an telegram group
Hello im trying to make a program that finds raydium tokens with specified details (marketcap,volume,liquidity,how many holders,etcetera)in typescript/javascript/python, and then sends the token information to a telegram group. What would i need to have and do to make it?
